# Get access to data directory for private data storage

Tags: android, file-permissions, data-storage, android-device-monitor

I develop an Android application and I would store some JSON data on the phone in private mode. I'll check if the file is created in the `data/data/<package-name>/shared_prefs` directory, but I don't get the correct permissions.

I use Android Device Monitor to check it. Here you've a screenshot of the monitor. When I click on the `data` directory, it doesn't open.

[image: Screenshot of monitor]
<sup>(Click on image for full screen)</sup>

How could I give the `data` directory and the files the correct permissions to access it and read or write file to it?

Here you've more information about my application

- **Minimum API version:** 19
- **Minimum Android platform:** Andoid 4.4 (KitKat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot get access to this directory from "outside" (only if it's a rooted device). From your app you have permission to access to this folder by default (both read and write). Just call the `getFilesDir()` to access to the folder.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getFilesDir()

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the `/data` folder having a non-rooted device

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand `a non-rooted device`.

Comment: In other words: you need an Android rooted smartphone to access the `data` folder. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_(Android_OS)